# Unable to connect to the Docker Container from the host browser on MacOS

Tags: macos, docker

I' am trying to deploy docker container on Mac machine. I ran the command:

```
     docker run -P -it clickstream-collector_csapi -c "test_config.yml".
     output: ts=2020-02-24T17:25:43Z lvl=info msg="Starting Collector"
     ts=2020-02-24T17:25:43Z lvl=info msg="Start producer" service=collector           
     brokers=kafka.dev:9102
     ts=2020-02-24T17:25:44Z lvl=info msg="Starting HTTP service"
     ts=2020-02-24T17:25:44Z lvl=info msg="Starting server on" addr=0.0.0.0:13425
```

However I can't launch 0.0.0.0:13425 on my Mac , it shows me "This site can’t be reached0.0.0.0 refused to connect".  It looks like my local machine doesn't look the docker . I know that Mac has some peculiarities but I pointed -p ( as I thought it should enough). Thanks a lot beforehand

Answer (score 0):

The `docker run -P` (capital “P”) option asks Docker to pick a host port.  That will almost always be a different port number from the one inside the container.  You can print out the port number by using `docker ps` to find the container ID, and then `docker port 0123456789ab` to print out the actual port mapping.  Once you’ve found the port number, you can use the special hostname `localhost` or the matching special IP address 127.0.0.1 and that port number to reach your container (not 0.0.0.0, a special address that means “everywhere”).

In typical use you’ll explicitly specify both host and container ports with a `-p` (little “p”) option, and also specify a `--name` so that you can find the container later.

```
docker run \
  -it \
  -p 13425:13425 \
  --name clickstream_collector \
  clickstream-collector_csapi \
  ...
```